# Why does Entity Framework only cascade single item in a collection?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, cascade

I have a Code First EF 5.0 model which has the following structure:

```
public class Widget 
{
    public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
    public virtual AddWidget(Widget widget)
    {
        Guard.NotNull(widget);

        if (Widgets == null)
        {
            Widgets = new List<Widget>();
        }

        Widgets.Add(widget);
    }
}
```

When I try to save a new transient `Product` with more than one added `Widget`, only the first `Widget` added is saved:

```
// ProductManagementContext is a DbContext
// ProductManagementContext.Products is a DbSet<Product>
using(var context = new ProductManagementContext())  
{
    var product = new Product();
    product.AddWidget(new Widget() { Name = "Foo" } );
    product.AddWidget(new Widget() { Name = "Bar" } );
    context.Products.Add(product);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

At this point, only "Foo" exists in the `Widget` table. I used SQL Server Profiler to check the data going to the database, and only one `INSERT` statement is issued for the first `Widget` in the collection that has two added.

Why isn't EF cascading on both new entities?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant or not, but why is the collection initialized in the AddWidget() method, instead of in the Product constructor?

Comment: I'm curious what difference that makes? From a design standpoint, it's overeager initialization, but there could be some pragmatic reason EF imposes to override the design decision, for example capturing property state after construction. Even so, since I mutate the value via the property accessor, there should be no difference in behavior.

Comment: That's a silly question, but I'll ask it anyway: you have the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute on all of the IDs, right?

Comment: I assume this is part of a larger project. Did you try to extract only these pieces into a test project (console app for example) in order to reproduce it in a simpler context? I would be surprised if the problem (which is not normal behaviour) occurs in the test project as well.

Comment: Are you using any specific libraries that we're not aware of? Where's `Guard` coming from? I'm also curious of why you have all fields as `Virtual`. The only field that need to be virtual, from what I can see in your example, is `public virtual ICollection<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }`. Does your code really compile when you define `AddWidget`? I need to define a return parameter as well. However, I've tried your code in VS2013 using EF5 and both Foo and Bar are saved in the database so I haven't been able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Since you aren't using data attributes to tell EF how to construct your models in the database, can we see the Fluent API? If you're not using that, then where are you telling EF how to treat your primary keys?

Comment: It is Code-First, no attributes are needed since I'm just using out-of-the-box conventions.

Comment: Did you get this worked out? I'm having the same problem. And, I'm definitely not using a virtual Id.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not reproducible with the code given. I've much copied and pasted it, fixed the compilation issue (AddWidget needs a return type), removed the call to `Guard`, run it and seen both the Widgets appear in the database.

Here is the complete code. Hopefully you can spot where your code differs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EF_SO_Q
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new ProductManagementContext())
            {
                var product = new Product();
                product.AddWidget(new Widget() { Name = "Foo" });
                product.AddWidget(new Widget() { Name = "Bar" });
                context.Products.Add(product);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Widget
    {
        public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public virtual Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
        public virtual void AddWidget(Widget widget)
        {

            if (Widgets == null)
            {
                Widgets = new List<Widget>();
            }

            Widgets.Add(widget);
        }
    }

    public class ProductManagementContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not that sure, but i think it's because of the virtual keyword in the id.

You said it's code first, and a key in a db represent an immutable property. Allowing that parameter to be overridden is confusing, and probably not correct...

Also the lists of subelements are defined as follow `this.Widgets = new HashSet<Widget>();` wich is more generic of a list ... i'll give it a shot

P.s. i've used model first